flextable crashing when calling as_flextable() or labelizor() functions
I tried to create a flextable, but it would always stop with an error.
Here an example from the flextable documentation (labelizor help page):
library(flextable)
z <- summarizor(
    x = CO2[-c(1, 4)],
    by = "Treatment",
    overall_label = "Overall"
)

ft_1 <- as_flextable(z, separate_with = "variable")

Running this on my system will stop with an Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (simplify = FALSE). This is from a call to as_flextable(). But I got the same error when calling e.g. labelizor().
Here is the complete output of the above code, including some information on my session:
Restarting R session...

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux 2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /opt/R/4.0.3/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/R/4.0.3/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3   
>
> library(flextable)
> z <- summarizor(
+     x = CO2[-c(1, 4)],
+     by = "Treatment",
+     overall_label = "Overall"
+ )
> ft_1 <- as_flextable(z, separate_with = "variable")
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (simplify = FALSE)
>
> traceback()
7: apply(curr_content_columns, 2, function(x) {
       lapply(x, function(x) {
           x$txt[x$txt %in% levs] <- labs[match(x$txt, levs, nomatch = 0)]
           x
       })
   }, simplify = FALSE)
6: labelizor(x = x, j = j, labels = labels, part = p)
5: labelizor(x = ft, j = labj, labels = x$use_labels[[labj]], part = "all")
4: as_flextable.tabulator(tab, ...)
3: as_flextable(tab, ...)
2: as_flextable.summarizor(z, separate_with = "variable")
1: as_flextable(z, separate_with = "variable")
>
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Amazon Linux 2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /opt/R/4.0.3/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/R/4.0.3/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] flextable_0.9.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_2.3.1               Rcpp_1.0.13             fontBitstreamVera_0.1.1 compiler_4.0.3          later_1.3.2            
 [6] gfonts_0.2.0            tools_4.0.3             uuid_1.2-1              digest_0.6.27           evaluate_0.14          
[11] jsonlite_1.7.2          lifecycle_1.0.3         rlang_1.1.1             shiny_1.9.1             cli_3.6.1              
[16] rstudioapi_0.13         crul_1.5.0              curl_4.3                fontLiberation_0.1.0    xfun_0.44              
[21] fastmap_1.2.0           xml2_1.3.2              officer_0.6.6           knitr_1.48              gdtools_0.3.7          
[26] systemfonts_1.1.0       askpass_1.1             grid_4.0.3              glue_1.6.2              httpcode_0.3.0         
[31] data.table_1.14.8       R6_2.5.0                textshaping_0.4.0       rmarkdown_2.24          magrittr_2.0.1         
[36] fontquiver_0.2.1        promises_1.3.0          htmltools_0.5.8.1       mime_0.9                xtable_1.8-4           
[41] httpuv_1.6.15           ragg_1.3.2              openssl_1.4.3           crayon_1.3.4           
> 

The above example is from the flextable documentation. I tried running it from a fresh installation of flextable from CRAN. So I expected it to execute without issues.
I can only assume this has something to do with an incompatibility of a package version of one of the dependencies, or maybe the combination of base R version 4.03 with flextable 0.9.6?
But I'm really stuck. Any idea on what could have gone wrong here would be much appreciated.

Welcome to SO! I can reproduce your issue using flextable 0.9.6 and the rocker:tidyverse:4.0.3 docker image, whereas it works fine on my Mac running on R 4.4.1. From the error message it looks like flextable 0.9.6 requires R >= 4.1.0 as it calls apply with the simplify= argument which was introduced in 4.1.0 (see the NEW Features section on 4.1.0 here).

Note: I just filed an issue on GH.

Thanks @stefan! Unfortunately, I'm bound to the given R installation, but I'll try to figure out the last flextable version that was working with 4.0.

Already guessed that. I think you can try 0.9.4.

You are right, 0.9.4 is fixing the issue. (Didn't try 0.9.5 though.)
If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

For anyone who stumbles over the same issue. This should now be fixed in the dev version: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/655#issuecomment-2325253455
